# XPath is not clicking the CheckBox despite being correct

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

[[image: Elements Window]]

```
selectcheckbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"infiniteScroll\"]/div/div[1]/div/input")
selectcheckbox.click()
```

I have tried the above code to click on the checkbox and as it can be seen in the attached image the XPath mentioned in the above code seems correct because when we find this XPath in the elements window it gets highlighted.

Please suggest: is there anything missing in the code?

Comment: There's a significant difference: in the image you use `div[1]`, but in code you use `div[2]`. This may be crucial.

Comment: @zx485 Thank you for this but I have used div[1] in the real code as shown in the image. That was by mistake I wrote div[2] in the question. Now, I have edited it. But the issue persists. Again, thanks for pointing this out and correcting me.

Comment: If you can't find an element and the xpath works in the chrome developer console  try seeing if it's in any iframes or shadowroots.

Comment: Are you getting any `error` ? is there any `iframe` or `shadowroots`  in the `HTML` source?

Comment: @ ArundeepChohan
@ Akzy
Yes, there are iframes and shadow-roots but they are much below the highlighted syntax in the image. I believe if the XPath of the required checkbox doesn't go through any iframes or shadow-roots, then the presence of these might not impact the XPath. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get element by using class:

```py
selectcheckbox = driver.find_element(By.CLASS, "selectordersCBALL");
```

Comment: Thank you Aman for the prompt help. However, first of all, I could not find By.CLASS.
Available options are XPATH, LINK_TEXT, NAME, CSS_SELECTOR, CLASS_NAME, PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, ID and TAG NAME.
I have tried with both NAME and CLASS_NAME, but it is not working with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try with ActionChains

```
selectcheckbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"infiniteScroll\"]/div/div[1]/div/input")
selectcheckbox.click()

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(selectcheckbox ).click(selectcheckbox ).perform()
```

Comment: The code brings an error on the selectcheckbox.click() line. And even when I comment out this line (as we have a click in the actionchain line), that brings no error but also does not resolve the issue. It does not check the checkbox.